# Javascript not replacing InnerHTML in PHP Script

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, printing, innerhtml

I have been working on a Garry's Mod loading screen recently and basically I was attempting to 'simplify' the map name by replacing it with a phrase. However, it appears PHP isn't printing the array value.

```
$map = $_GET["map"];
$map_list = array (
    "gm_construct" => "Construct",
    "gm_flatgrass" => "Flatgrass"
);
if (in_array($map, $map_list) == true)
{
    if ($map == $map_list[1])
    {
        print("<script>document.getElementById('map_name').innerHTML = '" . print($map_list['gm_construct']) . "'</script>");
    }
    else if ($map == $map_list[2])
    {
        print("<script>document.getElementById('map_name').innerHTML = '" . print($map_list['gm_flatgrass']) . "'</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: any error it is giving ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple issues with how you're accessing the associative array `$map_list`. Use the following:

```
<?php
$map = "Flatgrass"; // $_GET["map"];
$map_list = array (
    "gm_construct" => "Construct",
    "gm_flatgrass" => "Flatgrass"
);
$key = array_search($map, $map_list);
if ($key !== false) {
    print("<script>document.getElementById('map_name').innerHTML = '" . $map_list[$key] . "'</script>");
}
```

If the `$_GET` value has a key in the `$map_list`, just use it directly to print the script.

Don't call `print()` inside a concatenated string (*it outputs directly to standard out, doesn't return a string*).  And, this reduces your code, by just having one `if` statement print out the script using the value passed in directly.

And, in your original code, you can't index `$map_list` using integers, as you have only used string keys making it an associative array.

Comment: Only problem with that is that it would print/return the incorrect phrase (Flatgrass) so after 20 minutes of headbanging thinking I managed to come up with this: $map_list[$map] and I also flip-flopped the array. The keys are now the values the values are now the keys. Then removing your key variable to finally get what I was looking for. Good Game! http://pastebin.com/c5c9Nb0Z (Final Edit)

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code :-

```
$map = $_GET["map"];
$map_list = array (
    "gm_construct" => "Construct",
    "gm_flatgrass" => "Flatgrass"
);
if (in_array($map, $map_list) == true)
{
    if ($map == $map_list["gm_construct"])
    {
        print("<script>document.getElementById('map_name').innerHTML = '" . print($map_list['gm_construct']) . "'</script>");
    }
    else if ($map == $map_list["gm_flatgrass"])
    {
        print("<script>document.getElementById('map_name').innerHTML = '" . print($map_list['gm_flatgrass']) . "'</script>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
print("<script>document.getElementById('map_name').innerHTML = '" . print($map_list['gm_construct']) . "'</script>");
```

to

```
print("<script>document.getElementById('map_name').innerHTML = '{$map_list['gm_construct']}'</script>");
```

or you can use

```
echo '<script>document.getElementById("map_name").innerHTML = "', $map_list['gm_construct'] ,  '"</script>';
```

is better.